# spingfox-swagger2 description in @Tag not honored

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using the following version of springfox-swagger2 libraries in my Spring MVC project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I would like to add description to my REST Controller using the following according swagger documentation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@Api(tags = {"Admin API"})
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {
    @Tag(name = "Admin API", description = "Admin interface to manage users")
})
public class AdminController {
```

However the `description` in `tags` is not reflected in swagger-ui.

It says the following:

**Admin API Admin Controller**

Instead of:

**Admin API Admin interface to manage users**

What I am missing?

Comment: Below answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found I had to configure the docket to see tag descriptions in generated docs:

```
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(SWAGGER_2)
        ...
        .tags(
            new Tag("Admin API", "Admin interface to manage users")
        );
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. I am not able to see description in front of Tag. Using swagger 2.8.0 version

Comment: Its works fine, @kick you should provide the  same  tag name which you provided in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that grabs the annotation from the controller (I find it nicer to keep things on the controller):

```
@Bean
public Docket docket(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    List<Tag> tags = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(SwaggerDefinition.class).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(entry -> Optional.of(entry.getValue().getClass().getAnnotation(SwaggerDefinition.class))
                    .map(swaggerDefinition -> Stream.of(swaggerDefinition.tags())
                            .map(tag -> {
                                String name = tag.name();
                                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                                    name = Paths.splitCamelCase(entry.getKey(), "-").toLowerCase(); 
                                }
                                return new Tag(name, tag.description());
                            }))
                    .orElse(Stream.empty()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    ...
            .tags(tags.get(0), tags.stream().skip(1).toArray(Tag[]::new)); 
}
```

This will grab any bean annotated with `SwaggerDefinition` so one might have to adjust if this picks up something extra. I initially used `getBeansOfType`.

The annotation doesn't need to specify the tag name. Like so:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = {
    @Tag(name = "", description = "Admin interface to manage users")
})
public class AdminController {
```

I use the `Paths.splitCamelCase` method to create the tag name to match the default.